# C# File.Exists on partially copied file

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say for example I had a 20gb file and I decided to copy it to "c:/folder/filename.ext". Obviously this would take some time to complete.

What would the the following return if it was executed whilst the copy was taking place?

```
File.Exists("c:/folder/filename.ext");
```

Comment: why don't you try by yourself?

Comment: You'll learn more if you try it yourself.  It's not hard to generate a large file after all.

Comment: I looked around and no one had answered the question, saves lots of people doing the same thing :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would the the following return if it was executed whilst the copy was taking place?

Assuming the process you are running your code under has sufficient privileges to read the file it will return `True` (don't forget that `File.Exists` returns `False` if the account doesn't have sufficient privileges to read the file even if the file exists). The `File.Exists` method doesn't care if the file is currently being written to or read from:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenWrite("test.dat"))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        });
        Thread.Sleep(10);

        // prints True
        Console.WriteLine(File.Exists("test.dat"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about, but I think it returns true if there is any file (full or partially copied).

If you need the state of you copy process you should check lenght, or use hashing (SHA1).